# How to hide Pycharm python interpreters

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I have previously set up several conda environments in PyCharm and made these environments "available to all projects". However, now I'm find that there are too many environments in the drop-down list.

Are there any easy ways to configure these "globally visible" environments and make them visible only to certain projects? It would be a pain to delete the environment and set it up again for each project.

Better still, are there any way to organise these project interpreters eg. put them into folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "Hide virtual environments associated with other projects" (Pycharm 2018.3) which reduces the size of the list:

[image]

Comment: but this doesn't allow me to change the interpreter from "available to all projects" to be associated with only certain projects.

Comment: yep, in that case your only option is to remove readd the interpreter